# How to merge the Live streaming video and audio in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, avmutablecomposition

I am developing video based application in IOS. In my application I need to merge video and audio.I have merged the local video and audio file but I am not able to merge the live streaming video and audio if I try to merge them means the app is crashed because of time duration. For merging I am using  the below code

```
    -(void) playerFunction
    {
             NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.digdang.com/media/VideoFolde/017141.mp4"];
    
//    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.educator.com:1935/mobile/mp4:testVideo.mp4/playlist.m3u8"];// these is totally not working
    
    
    
    NSString* audio_inputFileName = @"audio.mp3";
    NSString* audio_inputFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],audio_inputFileName];
    NSURL*    audiopath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];

    NSString* videoName = @"output.mov";//outputdata
    NSString *savepath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
    
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    
    
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:savepath ] == YES){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savepath error:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"File not found");
    }
    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;
    
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:options];
    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL: audiopath options:options];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    NSLog(@"%@",[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]);
    NSLog(@"%f", CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration));
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack scaleTimeRange:video_timeRange toDuration:audioAsset.duration];
    
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
    
    
    
    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    _assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    
  
    NSURL    *savetUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savepath];

    _assetExport.outputURL = savetUrl;
    _assetExport.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    
    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         switch (_assetExport.status)
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 //   export complete
                 
                 NSLog(@"Export Complete");
                 //------>>> // From Here I want play movie using MPMoviePlayerController.<<<---------
                 [self play];
//                 [self performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 
                 //                export error (see exportSession.error)
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 
                 //                export cancelled
                 break;
                 
         }
         
         
     }
     
     ];

    
    NSLog(@"savepath :%@",savepath);
    }
```

Please some body help me

Comment: try passing CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) in insetTimeRange of compositionCommentaryTrack

Comment: The app crashing because of that line only sir. The app is crashing in the below line         [compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

Comment: cause while live streaming may be we are not getting right videoasset duration...

Comment: but in audioasset we have larger duration than videoasset duration

Comment: yes correct while printing the videoasscet.duration it showing me 0.00000

Comment: is there is any suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: there must be ) ..jst matter of some tym...

Comment: try using kCMTimeIndefinite instead of videoAsset.duration

Comment: I got this error sir while passing the live straming url ExportSessionError: The requested URL was not found on this server

Comment: ok...its working.thts gud...

Comment: no sir its showing me an error the video is not playing at all any suggestion for this..?

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving right Live Video URL to play.

In your code you have passed local video URL inside documents directory.
`NSString  *fileNamePath1 = @"Egg_break.mov";` instead of this u should pass some URLString from server.

e.g.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qtdevseed.apple.com/addemo/ad.m3u8"] options:nil];
```

Comment: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.digdang.com/media/VideoFolde/017141.mp4"]
        AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil]; While passing this also I am goting the same error

Comment: there is problem in url u r giving...check one of the ios tutorial which plays live stream video and check ur link...

Comment: Its playing in the mpmovie player and avplayer